# Replacement for DropEvent#getDragType

Tags: java, richfaces

I am migrating from RichFaces 3.3 to RichFaces 4.1. In RichFaces 3.3 there was a method called getDragType on the class DropEvent, now in 4.1 it has gone. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there does not seem to be a clean and simple solution to this problem, I am using a hack to achieve to same result:

```
<rich:dragSource id="selectedField" type="selectedField" dragValue="#{elem.position}" dragIndicator="indicator" />

e.getDragSource().getId()
```